# Removing personal Email Signature while using Organization Wide Email Address

Tags: apex, email

I am using Apex **SingleEmailMessage** to send out an email message, and utilizing the **setOrgWideEmailAddressId** to make sure this e-mail appears coming from a company e-mail and not from a specific user.

If users have a personal signature set up, the signature gets appended to the bottom of the e-mail message. How to avoid this personal signature?

Apex code that send email message:

```
 public static void sendEmail(String subject,String body, String address, String ccAddress) {

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String[] toAddresses = new String[] {address};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    if(ccAddress!=null) {
        String[] ccAddresses = new String[] {ccAddress};
            mail.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses);
    }
    mail.setSubject(subject);
    mail.setPlainTextBody(body);

    OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'my@company.com'];
    if ( owea.size() > 0 ) {
        mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.get(0).Id);
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

}
```

Comment: Which users are you referring here who have personal signature? Where is that signature, is that on the email template you are using?

Comment: We have set up signature here for users.  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000001133&type=1

Comment: What is in your email template and type of the template that you are using will help here.

Comment: We are not using email template.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SingleEmailMessage` extends `Email` class and inherits all its method. Refer to below excerpt from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_constructors).

> SingleEmailMessage extends Email and inherits all of its methods. All base email (Email class) methods are also available to the SingleEmailMessage objects.

To stop sending signature as part of the email, you need to use the following method from the base *[Email](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_base.htm#apex_classes_email_outbound_base)* class:

```
mail.setUseSignature(false);
```